# Possible glitch in Unity's TMP_InputField, extra invisible character?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text, input-field

Text created using TMP_InputField in Unity (Content Type: Standard) have one extra invisible character in the name! (In C# filename.Length  (which will return you the length of the string) is returning 1 more than what I can read.)

Does somebody understand why this might be happening? Could it be a bug in the TextMesh Pro? I struggle finding any info on this behavior.

I spent past 4 days figuring out why Unity can't find some files I previously saved (using my Unity project) in the folder, even though files WERE there and even when I was writing the exact path from the explorer. Note: I don't think it has something to do with permissions, I already tried that

Comment: funny thing...it is hard to reproduce. As if the invisible extra character was added over time. Like if it was added the second day...

Comment: can you print what character it is? (hex code)

Comment: Yeah i detect it using https://www.textmagic.com/free-tools/unicode-detector ... how did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and i found that i was accessing the inner text property with (TextMeshProUGUI) component not the Input field itself .. the right way is to access the input field with `<TMP_InputField>.text` 
Here is the original answer 
https://forum.unity.com/threads/textmesh-pro-ugui-hidden-characters.505493/

Comment: Hello , did you encouter after using the " <TMP_InputField>.text"  the issue is still there?